# Is there any difference between 'all real numbers' and '$(-\infty, \infty)$'

Tags: notation, terminology, real-numbers

I've just thought about this.

All the textbooks I've been looking at for pre-calc,

the domains are always written as 'all real numbers', whereas my calculus textbooks would rather write them as '$(-\infty, \infty)$.

Is there any difference using the terms vice versa (implicitly)?

Comment: The easiest way to represent that set is a single character – $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference: $\Bbb R = \left]-\infty,+\infty\right[$. Writing it like this serves to get you used with the symbol $\infty$, I guess (mostly psychological reasons?). Also, there will be a time when you'll need to use concepts dealing with the extended real line, so it will be natural to talk about: $$\left]-\infty,+\infty\right], \quad \left[-\infty,+\infty\right[, \text{ and } \left[-\infty,+\infty\right].$$

Comment: (In case OP doesn't know: $]a,b[$ is another notation for $(a,b)$; also, $]a,b]$ is another notation for $(a,b]$.)

Comment: I should have thought of that. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: So in the context of all real numbers, the definitions specifies all real numbers to be in the domain of -infinity to +infinity all the times?

Comment: Yes. The point is that $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are **not** real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The notation $(-\infty, \infty)$ in calculus is used because it is convenient to write intervals like this in case not all real numbers are required, which is quite often the case. eg. $(-1,1)$ only the real numbers between -1 and 1 (excluding -1 and 1 themselves).

Answer (score 1):

As far as precalculus is concerned, there is no difference.

Comment: Is there a difference in some other context?

Comment: Just in case there was, I made it clear there was none in the world of precalc or calc.

Comment: This answer is correct and the author was just explaining where they were sure about their knowledge.  I don't think it should be downvoted, and my comment definitely wasn't intended to point out any kind of inadequacy.

Comment: Yes. Because if we are talking about $\mathbb{N}$ for example, then the interval $ (-\infty,\infty)$ is not the same as the real numbers.